# docx4j-ImportXHTML : handle HTML characters in docx

Tags: jakarta-ee, docx, docx4j

I have a docx document containing :

[image]

I want to transform it into : 
[image]

I have tried the docx4j-ImportXHTML code from sample https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/DocxToXhtmlAndBack.java
But it doesn't transform the

> `<li><ul>`

into a docx list .

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: You'll need to get the XHTML into a String, then use https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples/ConvertInXHTMLFragment.java

Comment: Lists are handled with https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/in/xhtml/ListHelper.java